# calculation of total capacity of Bank of 3 single phase transformer?

Tags: transformer, autotransformer

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJYaR.jpg)

This is a nameplate of single phase auto-transformer. However in this transformer i'm not sure how do I get the capacity of this transformer. 3 of these transformers are connected in to form delta-star connection and I also would like to calculate the total capacity of the bank.

Why is in the rated power, the values are divided by 3? because they are made to be connected as a bank?

Comment: that is correct   250MVA total

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 so the bank has 250MVA  and a single transformer also has 250MVA is that right?

Comment: no a single is 1/3 of the bank